# How can I independently adjust alpha clip with duplicate textures?

Tags: texturing, shaders, transparency, shader-nodes

I have an imported object with 2 .png textures. Under material>settings I can adjust the clip threshold and one texture will gradually appear over the other. If I duplicate the object, I cannot do the same for duplicates unless I turn on backface culling or go into the shader editor and change the Alpha from Straight to Premultiplied, and even then that only works once. My goal is to be able to duplicate the object with duplicates of the .png textures and be able to adjust the clip threshold independently of the others. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alpha clip is a material setting, not an object setting.  Any time you change it, you're going to be changing it on all objects that have that material (and, you're only going to be changing it for those faces assigned to that material.)

By default, Blender leaves materials linked when you duplicate objects.  You can tell it that you want it to unlink these materials on duplication in preferences, in the editing tab, by enabling duplicate data/material.  Once you do this, every object you duplicate will have its own copy of the material, and so changing the alpha clip on one will have no effect on any of the others.

Comment: I have actually checked Material under Duplicate Data after watching a video suggesting to do so. Is there any way I can send you a video of my problem?

Comment: Yes, you could for instance upload a video to youtube and put a link in your question.

Comment: https://youtu.be/7Xw7hqJiEoQ?si=IzHl7q_9vGO9-yKg Here ya go.

Comment: While I would feel more comfortable examining a file-- it's difficult to make sure that I'm following what's happening in a video-- I believe that you're seeing buggy behavior.  The materials you're showing are two different materials, seen by .001 and .003 appended to their names, and changing the backface culling or clip threshold on one shouldn't affect the other.  (But note, the image texture node is shared between those materials, and settings made to it should affect both materials.)

Comment: If I were to attach the .blend file, would you be willing to take a look at it? And if it is in fact a bug could you tell me how I go about going through the proper channels to get it fixed? I'm sorry that this is dragging on, I'm just really invested in a project and desperately need to get past this if at all possible.

Comment: I'll probably take a look at it (no promises, but I'm inclined to do so.)  Make sure that you send a file that has all of the things imported into it.  Packing textures into the file would be ideal.  Best way to report a bug is via help menu -> report a bug, which will open a browser window incl. some instructions.

Comment: So I've run into a new problem. I have a .dff file import addon and the file I'm doing all of this with is a .dff with a .png material. I tried recreating the scenario by adding a plane and attaching the .png textures to it. The problem is, only one of the textures are visible when I do this. I even tried importing one .png as an Image As Plane and putting the second texture over it but I get the same result. I'm doing all of this not wanting to assume you have the same dff addon. Any advice?

Comment: I don't have dff addon or know what a dff is.  I do recommend understanding some of the basics (like setting up shaders reading png images.)  What I'd recommend doing is posting a question on blenderartists.org, in their materials section, because it allows for more convenient back&forth than BSE for working through problems like this.  I personally don't check the material section of that board, but if you post a link to a thread, I'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you, and again, I'm sorry this dragged on for so long. You've been very helpful.